# Nonexistence of a holomorphic function on $\{1<|z|<3\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an old complex analysis qualifying exam problem which I have no clue.

Let $A=\{1<|z|< 3\}$. Show that there does not exists a holomorphic function $f:A\to \mathbb C$ such that for all $z\in A$
$$\left|\frac{f^2(z)}{z}-1\right|< 1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality $|w-1| <1$ implies by squaring $ \Re w >0$; hence $g(z)=f^2(z)/z$ has positive real part which means that its degree (winding number wr to zero) is $0$; but $\deg g=2\deg f+\deg {1/z}=2\deg f+1$ is odd; contradiction!

($2\pi i \deg \frac{1}{z}=\int_{|z|=1}dz/z=2\pi i$, so $\deg \frac{1}{z}=1$)

Comment: Thank you. In fact, I realize the obstruction should be the square power of $f$ but it didn't occur to me to consider the degree. It helps a lot.

Comment: happy to be of help